# How to set Firebase Realtime database rules to read only child node?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a node called profiles that have a list of id's.
I want to allow read access to the child nodes only and prevent reading all profiles.

This is what I have in rules, but it allow to read all profiles.

```js
{
  "rules": {
      "profiles":{
        ".read": true,
        ".write": false  
      }
  }
}
```

and this is what I have under profiles

```js
{
  "1" : {
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "test1"
  },
  "2" : {
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "test2"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the values in this JSON? So what are the `"1"` and `"2"` keys, and what is the meaning of `"id" : "1"`? Both might be more readily apparent if you show a snippet of the actual JSON from your database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'll store each user's profile under a key that has the value of their Firebase Authentication UID. So:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "uidOfUser1": {
      "id" : "1",
      "name" : "test1"
    }
    "uidOfUser2": {
      "id" : "2",
      "name" : "test2"
    }
  }
}
```

In that case you can secure it with these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "profiles": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants read access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the security rules the value of `auth.uid` is the UID of the user that is currently signed in to Firebase Authentication. There is no way to spoof this value, so it's a great way to secure data access. The above rules allow a user to read a specific profile when their `auth.uid` matches the key of the profile. So `uidOfUser1` or `uidOfUser2`.

Also check out the [Firebase documentation on securing user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security), which describes it in more detail.

Comment: so basically $user_id means what ever child name is give it this rule? because I might have a dynamic child key on one of the roots.

Comment: Yes, the `$` variable in the rules means that: 1) the rules under that apply to any node that doesn't have a literal match, 2) the key becomes available in rules under it by the `$` variable name. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments. Note that by now I've answered two of your questions with links to the documentation on security rules, so I highly recommend you read that entire section and save yourself some time: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/